# Prove that $f(x) \leq 1$ for all $x \geq 0$ when $f'(x)\leq 0$ for all $x>0$ such that $f(x)>1$ and $f(0)=1$

Tags: calculus, analysis

Let $f:[0, \infty) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a function and assume that:

- $f$ is continuous on $[0,\infty)$
- $f$ is differentiable on $(0,\infty)$
- $f'(x)\leq 0$ for all $x>0$ such that $f(x)>1$; and
- $f(0)=1$

Prove that $f(x) \leq 1$ for all $x \geq 0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose there is $y \geqslant 0$ such that $f(y) > 1$ and let

$$x = \sup \{ x \in [0, y] : f(x) \leqslant 1 \}$$

so from continuity $f(x) = 1$. But from the MVT there is $\xi \in (x, y)$ such that

$$f'(\xi) = \frac{f(y)-f(x)}{y-x} > 0$$

but $f(\xi) > 1$ which contradicts one of the assumptions.

Answer (score 0):

If $f(y)>1$, let $z=\sup\{0<x<y: f(x)=1\}$. Apply MVT to prove the existence of $c\in(z,y)$ such that $f'(c)>0$. Apply Bolzano to prove that $f(c)>1$.